# Setup Multiple User Webdav with database authentication

Tags: mysql, tomcat, java, webdav

I have setup a Webdav Server in my Local Tomcat Server. I am looking to setup authentication using MySQL. The database will contain the user login credentials as well as the folders the user has access to. User should be able to view only the folders and files mapped to his user name. Any Ideas on how to implement this?